# How to use Microsoft xsd.exe with TrainingCenterDatabasev2 Schema?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have TCX exercise files which are written using the schema at https://www8.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabasev2.xsd.  I have been using them for years with Java and JAXB.  I am trying to write a C# application to do the same thing.  It is not going well.  I can generate C# classes using xsd.exe as provided by Visual Studio.  However, they do not make sense to me and cannot be used to deserialize my TCX files.

The basic structure of TCX files (at least the part in which I am interested) is they have a number of Activities containing a number of Laps containing a number of Tracks containing a number of Trackpoints.  The Trackpoints have latitude, longitude, and heart rate as the main items of interest.

The xsd-generated C# classes have an Activity_t[], an ActivityLap_t[], and a Trackpoint_t[][].  There is no Track_t[] and the string Track_t does not appear in the file even though it is in the .xsd, for example in this excerpt for the Lap and Track.

```
<xsd:complexType name="ActivityLap_t">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="TotalTimeSeconds" type="xsd:double"/>
            <xsd:element name="DistanceMeters" type="xsd:double"/>
            <xsd:element name="MaximumSpeed" type="xsd:double" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="Calories" type="xsd:unsignedShort"/>
            <xsd:element name="AverageHeartRateBpm" type="HeartRateInBeatsPerMinute_t" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="MaximumHeartRateBpm" type="HeartRateInBeatsPerMinute_t" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="Intensity" type="Intensity_t"/>
            <xsd:element name="Cadence" type="CadenceValue_t" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="TriggerMethod" type="TriggerMethod_t"/>
            <xsd:element name="Track" type="Track_t" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xsd:element name="Notes" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="Extensions" type="Extensions_t" minOccurs="0">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>You can extend Training Center by adding your own elements from another schema here.</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="StartTime" type="xsd:dateTime" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="Track_t">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Trackpoint" type="Trackpoint_t" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

I don't understand how to deal with the [][] nor why it would be generated.  And as mentioned it fails to parse.

> error CS0030: Cannot convert type
>   'TrainingCenterDatabaseV2.Trackpoint_t[] to
>   TrainingCenterDatabaseV2.Trackpoint_t.

(The namespace I used is TrainingCenterDatabaseV2.)

This is the code used to deserialize:

```
private const string NS_TrainingCenterDatabase_v2 = "http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2";

XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TrainingCenterDatabase_t),
                NS_TrainingCenterDatabase_v2);
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fs);
TrainingCenterDatabase_t tcx = (TrainingCenterDatabase_t)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Not knowing where to go with this I tried the Visual Studio plugin, xsd2code++.  This generates sensible C# classes with  List<Activity_t>, List<ActivityLap_t>, and List<Trackpoint_t>.  It also does not have Track_t, which seems to be somewhat superfluous.

However, it also fails to parse.  I believe the problems here have to do with the lack of annotations it generates, compared to the ones generated from xsd.exe.  I believe the problem is that it cannot handle the namespaces without those annotations, but I have seen no way to set options to get around that.  As stated, I am not experienced with deserialization in C#.  For my current purposes I have implemented reading the TCX files using XDocument rather than deserialization.  However, I am curious as to why what I tried did not work, especially since xsd.exe has been around for a long time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with the `xsd.exe` tool itself. I would recommend using [LinqToXsd](https://github.com/mamift/LinqToXsdCore) (requires .NET Core 2.1), which is another Microsoft-developed technology for accessing XML data using an XSD; it's also more advanced than `xsd.exe` and in my quick testing appears to fully handle the above Garmin training center database schema without issue.

Also if you cannot install .NET Core on your machine, you can use this [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqToXsd) instead. The .NET Core version requires .NET Core 2.1 to actually generate code, but that generated code that can be used in an app that targets .NET Framework 4.6.2 and above.

Comment: Thanks.  (I see your name is associated with these packages.)

I did install LinqToXsd and was able to generate C# files that look to be  sensible.  However, you need the NuGet package to resolve the calls in the Xml.Schema.Linq namespace in the generated files.

After getting all that straight, I get:

There is an error in XML document (1, 40). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: <TrainingCenterDatabase xmlns='http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2'> was not expected.

So far I have not figured out why and it has got late.

Comment: I have looked at this more.  I implemented GPX 1.1 from https://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd and got the same error.  It turns out GPX works with the C# files for xsd.exe.  I am doing the same thing in both cases.  The deserialization code code is the same as in the original post (except changed to do GPX).  I tried adding XMLRootAttribute and TypeAttribute annotations (as in the xsd.exe versions) to the root element, but that didn't help.  So I am stuck.

Comment: Also the namespace generated for GPX was www.topografix.com.GPX.1.1, which is invalid.  I changed it to www.topografix.com.GPX_1_1.  This should not affect its working or not.

Comment: Part of the problem is namespaces.  These are arbitrary strings and don't have to be the ones from www.garmin.com.  I expect why xsd.exe usually works is that it is not used with these types of namespaces.  As I said, I am inexperienced and don't know how to handle deserialization when the files have different namespaces or how to avoid the namespace issues with what I have.

Comment: LinqToXsd can handle multiple namespaces just fine, each XML schema namespaces should get mapped to its own CLR (.NET) namespace. I've built an example project to illustrate it, see here: https://github.com/mamift/GarminTest. 

Both `gpx.xsd` and `garminTrainingCenterDb.xsd` files exist in the same project. Try seeing if you can compile and run the example console app in the above github link. Note: it targets .NET 4.8, you might have to re-target to your specific version. The code supports .NET 4.6.2 and above.

Comment: Thank for making the example.  The difference is that you use TrainingCenterDatabase.Load(fileName) instead of the (TrainingCenterDatabase_t)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader) I was using.  Doing that, it works for me as well.  If it weren't for your help, I wouldn't have found LinqToXsd and all the stuff it requires.  It seems to be off the mainstream, but it works.  I'll mark it as a solution.

Comment: Ahh, so that's why you had trouble; sorry, I should've explained the API differences between `xsd.exe` and **LinqToXsd**. Both `xsd.exe` and **LinqToXsd** are Microsoft-built technologies, and both are Microsoft-abandoned, but fortunately **LinqToXsd**'s source code was publicly released, and I've been maintaining a .NET Core port since early 2019. Also, if you find a bug in it, please log an issue at Github: https://github.com/mamift/LinqToXsdCore/issues

Comment: Thanks for doing that. Wonder why they were abandoned.  Seems necessary.  Is there a replacement? I'm doing what I needed to do with XDocument, but would have preferred this way.  I'm ok but you could improve your solution for others.  I was unable to find the first package using NuGet Package Manager.  LinqToXsd appeared but it wasn't clear it was the right one.  I used the command-line commands in the GitHub README's.  I did need the second package to resolve the dependencies of the generated .cs.  And the Load thing.  Thanks, again.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no official-Microsoft maintained replacement. **xsd.exe** still ships with Visual Studio for backward-compatibility reasons and LinqToXsd was open sourced by Microsoft before it was officially released. LinqToXsd is definitely the superior option to use over xsd.exe however. Thanks for the feedback, I've updated the readme files to explain in more detail how to use it as well.